# Dar color a una parte del texto de una celda en googlesheets apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Buen día

Tengo este problema pero no se si es posible hacerlo, tengo que darle color a una parte de un texto que esta en una celda.
En una celda tengo el siguiente frase: "una aguja en un pajar", y solo quiero poner en color verde la palabra "aguja", pero todo lo demas quede en negro, y si es posible ponerle fondo y negrita mucho mejor.

he intentado esto, pero le coloca a toda la celda el color:

sh.getRange(1,1).setFontColor("green");

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Este código consegui con el generador de Macro de la SpreadSheet, y luego le modifique algunos parametros, en la celda A1 = marcar COLOR ROJO

```
function MacroCambiarColor() {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    var cell = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
    var valorCell = cell.getValue();
    var buscar  = "ROJO";  // en mayuscula porque uso toUpperCase()
    var vposini = valorCell.toUpperCase().indexOf(buscar);
    if( vposini > -1 ){

        vposfin = buscar.length + vposini;
        spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
              .setText(valorCell)
              .setTextStyle( vposini, vposfin, SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
              .setForegroundColor('#0000ff')
              .setBold(true)
              .build())
              .build());

    }
} // cierra function
```